# online Users android with callBack

Tags: php, android

Hi guys I need to know the count of online users in my app I write this PHP code so far (for add online)

```
 <?php
require_once 'config.php';  
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$con =mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT online FROM online_players");
$row =mysqli_fetch_array($con);
$plus = 1;
$add = (int)$row['online'] + $plus;

$sql = "UPDATE online_players SET online ="."'$add.'";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo json_encode($add);
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

This is working so well and I can minus on finish method but I want to know is there any way better without log in system to at least send me a call back to notiy my textView(show online members) online members is changed?

Comment: Note you can do this: `UPDATE online_players SET online = online + 1;`

Comment: I don't really understand the question are you mean is there a better way to do this in real-time without manually to do the operation on call back? maybe you should try socket io ?

Comment: yea thanks for that do you know anything about this? https://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/index.jsp

Comment: @Potato i just want when some one is call this code and the online users changed somehow i can update my textView

Comment: You could try to use socket io or any other real-time framework but to handle real-time in php is kinda a bit pain in the a** you could just use firebase which is more of a small integration into your system instead

Comment: @Potato do you think doing timed refresh with job scheduler is a standard way? i mean for battery